# Short story about a woman yearning for her dream home

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Years ago, I read a short story and I can’t find it.
It is about a couple who are part of the working poor—probably the 40s or 50s. The woman complains most of the time about their conditions. But she also buys design magazines and in her mind has the perfect home. She cuts out pictures of fabrics, furniture, colors. But she is never happy.

She gets sick and almost dies. She spends months in hospital. During that time, her husband takes their savings and using her design books, re-creates her dream home. With one problem. He can’t find a particular shade for one piece.

She comes home and sees what he has done and is finally content for the first time since he has known her.

What is the name of the short story? I have sought it for years.

Comment: It sounds like it might be Roald Dahl. He wrote some weird ones full of ironies like that.

Comment: Please could you give as as much information as you can, as per the tag info. Where did you read it, was it in an anthology, a magazine? Is it set in the US, Australia, France, Ireland? Absolutely anything you can recall is helpful, as are the names of any similar works you have already discounted.